# zlib: thread safe zalloc and zfree in C?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, malloc, zlib

I am using the zlib C library to decompress data received from a network stream, and I have two streams running in two separate NSThreads. As per zlib documentation, decompressing two different zlib streams in two threads requires zalloc and zfree to be thread safe. I am currently passing Z_NULL (my inflateinit code below)

```
zStream.zalloc = Z_NULL;
zStream.zfree = Z_NULL;
zStream.opaque = Z_NULL;
zStream.avail_in = 0;
zStream.next_in = Z_NULL;
int status = inflateInit(&zStream);
if (status != Z_OK)
    DLog(@"zlib setup error");
else
    DLog(@"zlib setup ok");
});
```

Does anyone have experience with using zlib for compressing multiple streams in separate threads? Has anyone seen a thread safe implementation of zalloc and zfree?

Comment: The degenerate case for zalloc and zfree are the libc malloc, calloc and free routines. They are thread safe.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by "degenerate case"?

Comment: By using Z_NULL for zalloc and zfree the code uses libc's malloc/calloc and free routines, and on Mac OSX/iOS these are thread safe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`malloc()` and `free()` on Mac OS X are already thread safe.  So just initialize the structure with `Z_NULL` as you're doing and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I am using them as is but getting a Zlib deflation error (-3). If the problem is not with zlib, it might be with my network streams themselves. Let me investigate this further and once I confirm that the problem is not with zlib, I will mark this answer as correct.

Comment: `-3` is a data error.  That means the data you are feeding `inflate()` is invalid.

Comment: yes the problem is with the input to zlib, not with zlib code.